# Erro de rpdefine no delphi Seattle

Tags: delphi-7

Estou tentando abrir uma aplicação que foi criada em Delphi 7 no Delphi Seattle, porém quando executo a aplicação esta ocorrendo o erro:

```
[dcc32 Fatal Error] ControleImpressoes.dpr(114): F2613 Unit 'rpdefine' not found.
```

Sou novo com a linguagem Delphi se souberem o que poderia ser isso

Comment: Pelo que eu pude observar, a classe ControleImpressoes necessita da Unit rpdefine, se não me falhe a memória quem usa isso é o componente Rave Report, você pegou na internet esse fonte?... talvez quem desenvolveu fez com que o programa dependesse do componente Rave Report. E o Delphi não tem mais o Rave Report como nativo, teria que dar uma pesquisada pelo componente para Seatle.

Comment: Pois é o problema esta em encontrar o rave report compatível para Delphi Seattle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, estava com o mesmo problema. Resolvi da seguinte forma:
1. Baixei e instalei o Rave Report 11.0.11 através do link "http://exirbox.com/post/102" e ;
2. Coloquei a posta do Rave Report,no Enviroment Path do Delphi, com base nas instruções do link "http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/uses-do-rave-reports-delphi-xe4/456934".

Espero ter ajudado!